# Is it safe to pass boost::variant to (from) dll?

Tags: c++, boost, variant

Consider this code

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> var_t;

// this interface class will be implemented in DLL
class producer
{
public:
  virtual var_t produce() = 0;
};

// this class will be implemented by DLL user and 
// pointer to object of this class will be passed to producer
// as callback interface
class produce_handler
{
public:
  virtual void handle_produce(const var_t&) = 0;
};
```

It is known that it is generally unsafe to pass STD objects through dynamic library boundary. What about boost types, especially variant?

Comment: same problems with boost as with std. always depend on compiler/compiler-version/boost version.

Comment: Also, there is a `std::string` in that `variant`: how magic do you think `variant` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that all modules involved share the same toolchain/options (i.e. ABI), there should be no real trouble<sup>**[1]**</sup>.

Regardless of this:

Also, if you know that the "other" module is never going to do anything other than store and pass a reference back to the caller, then there shouldn't be a problem either.

As soon as you start passing these things by value and/or indirecting the references/pointers in a "foreign" module I'd say you need to be very sure your platform supports this and test it.

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> outside separate issues, such as the ability to throw/catch exceptions across shared library boundaries; this is related bot not confined to `any` (or RTTI in general)